# Cannot get the dc piechart to display correctly

Tags: dc.js

I am using javascript to make a html dashboard. I am having problems with displaying the pie chart. I am wishing to use the table 'add length' data set to populate the pie chart. The add length data has the following json format.

[{"Add Length":30.0,"Week Ahead":59.16,"Last Week":0.0,"Q1 2017":0.0,"Q3 2017":0.0,"Q1 2017 Total":83.68,"Q3 2017 Total":83.21,"Target":0.0,"Natural Delivery Equiv %":0.0},{"Add Length":60.0,"Week Ahead":40.84,"Last Week":100.0,"Q1 2017":0.0,"Q3 2017":0.0,"Q1 2017 Total":0.0,"Q3 2017 Total":0.0,"Target":0.0,"Natural Delivery Equiv %":0.0}]

The add length table displays on the dashboard as follows. 
[image]

However when I display the pie chart on the dashboard I get the following image. 
[image]

From reading online this should work. This should have the pie chart populated by the add length table with the "Week Ahead" column. The bit of javascript I am using is given below.

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/txtimes1")
.defer(d3.json, "/txtimes2")
.defer(d3.json, "/txtimes3")
.defer(d3.json, "/txtimes4")
.defer(d3.json, "/txtimes5")
.await(makeGraphs);

function makeGraphs(error,txtimes1,txtimes2,txtimes3,txtimes4,txtimes5) {

var addl = txtimes1;
var channel = txtimes2;
var sale = txtimes3;
var daypart = txtimes4;
var day = txtimes5;
//Create a Crossfilter instance
//var ndx1 = crossfilter(prog);
var ndx1 = crossfilter(addl);
var ndx2 = crossfilter(channel);
var ndx3 = crossfilter(sale);
var ndx4 = crossfilter(daypart);
var ndx5 = crossfilter(day);

var AddlDim = ndx1.dimension(function (d) {
    return d["Week Ahead"];
});

var sentimentName = ndx1.dimension(function (d) {
    return d["Week Ahead"];
});

var sentimentGroup = sentimentName.group(function (d) {
    return d["Add Length"];
});

var sentimentPie = dc.pieChart("#sentiment-pie");

var addlength = dc.dataTable("#addl");

var pspace ="\xa0\u0025\xa0\xa0\xa0";
var space ="\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0";
var colour1="red";
var colour2="orange";
var colour3="FEE11";
var colour4="green";
var colour5="blue";
var colour6="purple";
var colour7="darkred";
var colour8="pink";

sentimentPie
    .width(415)
    .height(415)
    .radius(200)
    .innerRadius(50)
    .dimension(sentimentName)
    .group(sentimentGroup)

    .render()

    .label(function (d) {
        if (sentimentPie.hasFilter() && !sentimentPie.hasFilter(d["Week Ahead"])) {
            return d["Week Ahead"] + '(0%)';
        }
        var label = d.key;

            label += ' (' + d.key + '%)';

        return label;
    });

addlength
    .dimension(AddlDim)
    .group( function (d) { return ''; })
    .sortBy(  function(d) { return d["Week Ahead"]; })

    .columns([{
               label: "Add Length " + space,
               format: function (d) { return d["Add Length"]+space; }
              },
              {
               label: " Week Ahead " + space,
               format: function (d) { return  (d["Week Ahead"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour1); }
               },
              {
               label: "Last Week " + space,
               format: function (d) { return (d["Last Week"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour2); }
               },
              {
               label: "Q1 2017 " + space,
               format: function (d) { return (d["Q1 2017"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour3); }
               },
              {
               label: "Q3 2017 " + space,
               format: function (d) { return (d["Q3 2017"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour4); }
               },
              {
               label: "Q1 2017 Total " + space,
               format: function (d) { return (d["Q1 2017 Total"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour5); }
               },
              {
               label: "Q3 2017 Total " + space,
               format: function (d) { return (d["Q3 2017 Total"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour6); }
               },
              {
               label: "Target " + space,
               format: function (d) { return (d["Target"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour7); }
               },
              {
               label: "Natural Delivery Equiv " + space,
               format: function (d) { return (d["Natural Delivery Equiv %"] + pspace).fontcolor(colour8); }
               }
             ])

    .size(180)
    .beginSlice(0)
    .endSlice(10)
    .order(d3.descending);
```

If anyone could tell me why this isn't working, I would be most grateful.

Thanks

[My dashboard](http://127.0.0.1/txtimes)

Comment: the correct tag for dc.js is [dc.js] - that's why i missed this. [dc] is a desktop calculator for Unix.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem:

In order for the pie chart to be populated it requires a reduceSum.

```
var AddlGroup = AddlName.group().reduceSum(function (d) {return d["Week Ahead"]; 
});
```

This sums the values within that group. However, since there's one entry for each group, it returns the single row value for each row.